# How to extract list from a paragraph using Python and OpenAI

Tags: python, openai-api

I am trying to extract specific pieces of text, the bearings and distances, from a paragraph.  The paragraph is a description of a piece of land from a deed.  I would like to extract all the bearings and distances.  The text above was extracted using tesseract from an image so there are some misspellings and other errors.

Paragraph=

```
BEGINNING at a point in the centerline of O14 L-R. 641, formerly know as Beaver Road, 
50 fect wide, said point being the sane ag the point of berinning jabovenentioned in 
‘Parcel 1*; thence slong said canterline and along land now or forterly of Tremarco
Corporation, worth 33° 20° West, a distance of 65.29 feat to the true point of egimning;
thence, awsy from said centerline and stil along land now or fornerly of ‘Teemazco 
Corporatian, South 72° 36° 47" West, a distance of 120,76 feet to a point on the easterly line 
of Route 65, §.R. 0068, formerly known as New L.R. 641, 60 foot wide; thence, along said 
easterly Line, Horth 17° 23° 13" West, a Mistance of 268.00 feet to a point; thence, slong 
line of land of the Borough of Coaway, North 72° 36’ 422 Rant, a distance of $5.31 foet to 
point on the aforenantioned centerline of Old LR, 641; thence, along said centerline the 
following 3 courses and datance, Viz: ‘South 29° 09’ Eamt, a distance of 86.98 feet to a 
paint, South 30° 36° Bast, = distance of 91.55 feet to a point; South 33° 20° Bast, a distance 
of 97.47 feet to said true point of BROTMNING.
```

I used ChatGPT and it was able give me what I needed which is what I see below.

I am hoping to get something like this:

```
North 33° 20' West, a distance of 65.29 feet
South 72° 36' 47" West, a distance of 120.76 feet
North 17° 23' 13" West, a distance of 268.00 feet
North 72° 36’ 422 East, a distance of 5.31 feet
South 29° 09’ East, a distance of 86.98 feet 
South 30° 36° East, = distance of 91.55 feet
```

Code:

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")


# function that takes in string argument as parameter 
def comp(PROMPT, MaxToken=50, outputs=3): 
    # using OpenAI's Completion module that helps execute 
    # any tasks involving text 
    response = openai.Completion.create( 
        # model name used here is text-davinci-003 
        # there are many other models available under the 
        # umbrella of GPT-3 
        model="text-davinci-003", 
        # passing the user input 
        prompt=PROMPT, 
        # generated output can have "max_tokens" number of tokens 
        max_tokens=MaxToken, 
        # number of outputs generated in one call 
        n=outputs 
    ) 
    # creating a list to store all the outputs 
    output = list() 
    for k in response['choices']: 
        output.append(k['text'].strip()) 
    print (output)
    return output


PROMPT = """ 
Give bearings and distances from the text below.
  
Text:### 
BEGINNING at a point in the centerline of O14 L-R. 641, formerly know as Beaver Road, 50 fect wide, said point being the sane ag the point of berinning jabovenentioned in ‘Parcel 1*; thence slong said canterline and along land now or forterly of Tremarco Corporation, worth 33° 20° West, a distance of 65.29 feat to the true point of egimning; thence, awsy from said centerline and stil along land now or fornerly of ‘Teemazco Corporatian, South 72° 36° 47" West, a distance of 120,76 feet to a point on the easterly line of Route 65, §.R. 0068, formerly known as New L.R. 641, 60 foot wide; thence, along said easterly Line, Horth 17° 23° 13" West, a Mistance of 268.00 feet to a point; thence, slong line of land of the Borough of Coaway, North 72° 36’ 422 Rant, a distance of $5.31 foet to point on the aforenantioned centerline of Old LR, 641; thence, along said centerline the following 3 courses and datance, Viz: ‘South 29° 09’ Eamt, a distance of 86.98 feet to a paint, South 30° 36° Bast, = distance of 91.55 feet to a point; South 33° 20° Bast, a distance of 97.47 feet to said true point of BROTMNING.
### 
"""
comp(PROMPT, MaxToken=3, outputs=1)
```

But when I run my code I get this response:

```
['Starting Point']
```